# Can I download an rdl file from a SharePoint list?

Tags: reporting-services

I wonder if I can download an RDL file that was uploaded to a Sharepoint list. I want to upload it to our QA server, but I don't seem to find it anywhere since it was done by the developer before me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SSRS was configured in SharePoint Integrated Mode, then the RDL files should be saved in a document library somewhere. Should be easy enough to just download them upload to your QA box, and they should work fine I reckon. The tough bit for you sounds like locating them.

Comment: Yes, I may've not explained myself. The RDL file is in a Document library. The thing is there's no download link. If I click on the file the report opens up, and if I right click and select save target as, an HTML page is saved.

Comment: What happens if you use the EditControlBlock menu to select Send To -> Download a Copy ?

Answer (score 3):

Open the report folder in Windows Explorer view....:-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit the view and add the Edit control to the visibile columns?